# Message box were not showing when meeting desired minutes and seconds on timer

Tags: vb.net, timer

Could you help review what am I missing on the code. What i would want to achieve is to prompt a message box when the of every 49 minutes of each hour.

Already tried declaring the value of the minutes and seconds but it doesn't prompt a message when 49 minutes and 00 seconds where reach it only continous to tick

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Timer1.Start()
        If lblMinutes.Text = "48:" And lblsecond.Text = "00" Then

            MessageBox.Show("Please wait were updating the data table..")

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        lblHours.Text = Date.Now.ToString("hh:")
        lblMinutes.Text = Date.Now.ToString("mm:")
        lblsecond.Text = Date.Now.ToString("ss")
        lbltt.Text = Date.Now.ToString("tt")
    End Sub
```

I expect a message box everytime the timer reach the 49 minutes and 00 seconds of each hour

Comment: If my answer was helpful please accept it so future people looking at this may see that it is a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Timer1.Interval = 60000 '1 min
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Dim isec As Integer = 0
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

   isec += 1

   If isec = 49 Then
      MessageBox.Show("Please wait were updating the data table..")
      isec = 0
   End If

End Sub
```

Try This.

In regards to your code, the if statement in your button4 click event isn't firing constantly because it only goes through it once upon button click, so you click the button, timer starts, checks the label see if it "48:" then will exit the button click event and never check the label again unless you press the button again, understand? So maybe even put your whole "IF" statement into the Timer1.Tick event.

Events only occur when the trigger event happens. So in your case the IF statement in your button4 click event only is executed when the button is clicked. So unless you click the button on the exact time your looking for it won't display the message.